# Drawing 3D Lines with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, 3d, line

We all know there are no native functionality within WPF 4.5 to draw pure lines in 3D space on a viewport3D.

And I'm aware of the fact there are a few 3D-toolkits for WPF. But for my masterthesis I built my own 3D-engine. It's almost complete but i would like to be able to draw the wireframes of my object (for example to show tessellation of a sphere).
my engine can render almost every basic geometric form (cube, sphere, cone, cylinder, pyramid, ..)

have you any idea how to draw lines? (my only idea is to use a very thin cylinder or cube ... but i don't think that is very efficient because i have to render at least 8 points (12 triangles) for one single line)

Comment: You could make that cylinder 6 points (5 triangles) per line.

Comment: that's right. a slightly optimisation would be to draw a prism with 6 points. but i count 8 triangles in that case ;)

Comment: My best guess is to use the pixel shader to draw that wireframes.

Comment: that's the type of ideas i was searching for.
unfortunatelly i'm not into this topic and i have to do research first (i did shader once at the university 3 years ago ... and i have to admit this was not my favorite topic ;-) )

Comment: Well first of all WPF doesn't currently support 3D pixel shaders, and secondly even if it did a pixel shader wouldn't be of any use at all because they're applied during rasterization once it's already been decided which pixels are to be drawn in the first place. To do proper fixed-width wireframe geometry with z-buffering etc you need to specify primitive type and WPF simply doesn't support that yet. My advice would be to switch to XNA for your 3D stuff and render your XAML views over top with an Airspace Popup....or just fake it with cylinders like everyone else is suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

So you just pass the neccessary data to the pixel shader of your engine along with color, multisampling, width or whatever information it might need and draw that lines with PS.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with unitary-width lines and you don't mind rendering wireframed then you can go that way.

A more complete alternative is drawing quadrangles composed by two adjacent triangles. You can  use lines as primitives and take advantage of the geometry shader's capabilities and use it to generate the quad.

Create a geometry shader receiving the two points forming each line and outputting a triangle list. You just need to append four points to the output stream. Use the computations shown [in this paper](http://http.download.nvidia.com/developer/SDK/Individual_Samples/DEMOS/OpenGL/src/cg_VolumeLine/docs/VolumeLine.pdf) from NVIDIA, to calculate each of the four coordinates of the quad.

While the input of the geometry shader were lines, the output will be two triangles properly set up forming your line. Actually, this technique offers quite some flexibility since the quads are not constraint to being rectangles (i.e. each side can have different widths).